# SSIS forcing task successful but parent fails

Tags: ssis

I have a sequence container with two tasks.  First task is ok to fail but if the second task fails the container should fail.  I set the properties for the first task as

```
ForcedExecutionValue=0
ForceExecutionResult=Success
ForceExecutionValue=True
```

If both tasks are successful - regardless of the method why is the container (and therefore the package) failing ?

Tried to set a breakpoint on the first task for onerror, taskfailure and warning but none are firing which seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

Think I was able to work this out.  For the first task in addition to the settings in OP, the task needed OnError handler with propagate=false so the error would not be passed to the container.  Also make sure DisableEventHandlers = false